# Nginx load balancer > unicorn static assets not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

Just setup nginx as a load balancer for unicorn using the following guide [HERE](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scale-ruby-on-rails-applications-across-multiple-droplets-part-1)

My Vhost on the nginx load balancer is below.

```
upstream unicorn_app {
server 192.111.111.111:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
server_name app.com www.app.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# https SSL SPDY vhost
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
        server_name app.com www.app.com;

ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/app/app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/app/app.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache      shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!kEDH:!EDH:!CAMELLIA;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    add_header Alternate-Protocol  443:npn-spdy/3;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";


access_log /home/nginx/domains/app.com/log/access.log combined buffer=32k;
error_log /home/nginx/domains/app.com/log/error.log;

location / {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass http://unicorn_app;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}

}
```

The app seems to be running and serving requests apart from the css assets. Getting a 404 on them. Seems Nginx is not passing the asset requests to Unicorn to be served.

Comment: Please post the complete location block and also check execute permission on css assets.

Comment: Thats all thats in the location block from the guide that I followed. Checked permissions they are ok

Comment: @Steve Post the whole config or we can't help you.

Comment: The full vhost on the nginx load balancer is above